# Android : Custom Grid View Adapter with image and text error

Tags: android

I am creating a fragment called `Facility` which will have `GridView` containing images and `TextView`. For this I have created the `facilityfragment` and custom adapter class and two xml files.

1. row_grid
2. the gridview.xml.

In custom adapter I am able to show the images but how to link it with `row_grid` and show text in it. e.g; In the grid view there will be images and just below that a `TextView` describing each image. Below are the code segments

**fragment_facility_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewCustom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_grid.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**FacilityFragment**

```
public class FacilityFragment extends Fragment  {
    private GridView gridView;
    private ImageView imageView;




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facility_grid, container,
                false);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewCustom);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext()));

        return view;

}

}
```

**CustomGridViewAdapter**

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.bank, R.drawable.facility,
            R.drawable.gym , R.drawable.facility,
            R.drawable.facility , R.drawable.construct1,

    };

    public String[] mThumbNames = {
            "Bank", "Facility","Gym", "Facility","Facility","Construct"

    };

    // Constructor
    public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

As I am new to Android so facing such difficulties.

1. link `customadapter` to row_grid
2. show text below each image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change this line

```
 gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext()));
```

to

```
 gridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewAdapter(view.getContext()));
```

and the CustomGridViewAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.bank, R.drawable.facility,
            R.drawable.gym, R.drawable.facility,
            R.drawable.facility, R.drawable.construct1,

    };
    public String[] mThumbNames = {
            "Bank", "Facility", "Gym", "Facility", "Facility", "Construct"

    };
    private Context mContext;

    // Constructor
    public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


//        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
//        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
//        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
//        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;


        if (convertView == null) {

            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            viewHolder.imageViewItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            // store the holder with the view.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // object item based on the position

        // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
        viewHolder.textViewItem.setText(mThumbNames[position]);
        viewHolder.textViewItem.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.imageViewItem.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


        return convertView;

    }

    // our ViewHolder.
// caches our TextView
    static class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView textViewItem;
        ImageView imageViewItem;
    }


}
```

You did not worked on ImageView and TextView which were defined in XML layout and you were creating new ImageView only.

Hope this will help you to understand

Answer (score 0):

here you have tutorial how to use grids in android, in 4th point you have specified how to set adapter to the GridView
also in point 5 in getView Overriden method is shown how to fill text to cell
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting adapter call your adapter like this

```
gridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewAdapter(view.getContext()));
```

After you have to set your **row_grid.xml** in **getView()** method of your adapter like this, hope help this

```
      @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_grid.xml, parent, false);
                }
            ImageView imgView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
TextView txtView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
            imgView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
txtView.setText(mThumbNames [position]);
            return convertView ;
        }
```