# dynamically populate gridlayout from array

Tags: android, arrays, drawable, grid-layout

trying to build an app for my son (very new at this still) still reading and learning as much and quickly as i can. basically i've created a test app to work with but i'm trying to fill a gridlayout (this is only a 4x4 grid real app will be larger) from an array of images when i click a button.  i hope i can randomize the order of images (that was my next issue to figure out!) i can not get the images to load....

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//added new int[]
int[] pics = new int[]{R.drawable.e1, R.drawable.e2, R.drawable.e3,R.drawable.e4};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnDisplay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnDisplay:

           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid); //my grid
           // grid.removeAllViews(); //clears existing views..i think

            int items = 9; //number of items to dispaly in my grid
            int column = 3;
            int rows = 3;
            grid.setRowCount(rows);
            grid.setColumnCount(column);

          //  ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
           // iv.setImageResource(pics[4]);

            //grid.addView(iv,1);

            ////*******************************************************
            //squares = new int[4];
            // Put the images in the GridLayout.
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);
                iv.setImageResource(pics[i]);

            }


            break;
```

and the gridlayout from the xml

```
  <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:id="@+id/grid">

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Create adapter an set it to adapter.
Hre is  a sample example to do so.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428106/android-custom-grid-view-adapter-with-image-and-text-error

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use gridview and was able to make that work. From my previous reading I was under the impression that gridlayout was the way to go.